# Installing Visual Studio on Macbook Pro with Parallels/Windows 7

Tags: installation, dvd, iso-image, visual-studio-2008

I have a Visual Studio 08 ISO on a DVD. And I don't know how to install it. I thought I could insert it and install it, but there is more to it than that I see. I have a MacBook Pro with Parallels 6, so I also have Windows 7. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're running Windows 7 within Parallels 6, you can you mount the ISO through Parallels, then Windows will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount it with [software such as MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/download.htm) from a windows vm

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mount an iso with Parallels: Devices / CD/DVD1 / Connect image... The disk image will appear in Windows if a CD/DVD was inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with your DVD you will need to go to the main menu and select **Virtual Machine** then **Configuration** - on the screen that appears, select the Hardware tab and go to **CD/DVD 1** - there you can select the disk or virtual disk you want to connect your Windows 7 environment to.

A quick note on the above responses - if you have your Windows 7 environment setup to be shared with your Mac (as opposed to isolated - under the Options tab there are several such settings under the Security, Sharing and Applications items of the menu that is contextually bound to that main menu with General, Options and Hardware) - anyways the point is that if you're using a tool like Daemon Tools and you can't mount an image, such as an ISO, it may be that the image is in a folder that's native to your Mac. I ran into this issue when I had several ISO files in my downloads folder - since I set "Share Mac user folders with Windows", the downloads folder was actually the Mac user downloads folder - so I just created a directory within the Windows virtual hard disk and moved the ISO there - from there it worked like a charm :)

unfortunately I don't think this will help the original poster (given how long it has been since the original post), but hopefully it will help someone with this same issue down the road